# Heroku and i18n Problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, heroku

I'm having trouble getting i18n to work on heroku. 
I set:

```
I18n.default_locale = :de
```

in my environment.rb
and the translation is in config/locales/de.yml 
works perfect on my local machines but not so on Heroku. 
On heroku everything is in english. 
I don't think I need a special gem like i18n gem, cause I don't have it on my local machine either. 
Maybe someone has a solution to this?

Comment: Hello,
I have the same problem as Mark, did you find a solution that works?

Comment: He did mark an answer as accepted. If this didn't help, maybe this do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156765/heroku-i18n-locale-is-different-from-default-locale-works-fine-locally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the default local like this in your config.environment.rb:

```
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
  # ...
  config.i18n.default_locale = :de
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I found that worked for me, on heroku, was setting it manually in the application controller.

application_controller.rb

```
before_filter :set_locale

def set_locale 
  I18n.locale = 'fr-QC' || I18n.default_locale 
end
```

cheers