# Heroku language locale not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, localization, heroku

It seeems like my language locale on heroku is not working.

```
On my local mashine : 1. maj
Heroku              : 01 May 00:00
```

My view:

```
<%= l vind.udtraekkes, :format => :short %>
```

Locale:

```
en: 
  hello: "Hello world"
  views:
    pagination: 
      previous: "&laquo; Tilbage"
      next: "Næste side &raquo;"
      # active_support
  date:
    # See http://sproget.dk/svarbase/SV00000046/ and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_formats
    # either use traditional (2.10.03, 2. oktober 2003): "%e.%m.%y", "%e. %B %Y"
    # or international ISO 8601 format (2003-10-20): "%Y-%m-%d"
    # Note: some Windows distributions do not support %e - you may have to use %d instead
    formats:
      default: "%d.%m.%Y"
      short: "%e. %b"
      long: "%e. %B %Y"

    day_names: [søndag, mandag, tirsdag, onsdag, torsdag, fredag, lørdag]
    abbr_day_names: [sø, ma, ti, 'on', to, fr, lø] # Note: unescaped 'on' is parsed as true
    month_names: [~, januar, februar, marts, april, maj, juni, juli, august, september, oktober, november, december]
    abbr_month_names: [~, jan, feb, mar, apr, maj, jun, jul, aug, sep, okt, nov, dec]
    order:
      - :day
      - :month
      - :year

  time:
    formats:
      default: "%e. %B %Y, %H:%M"
      short: "%e. %B"
      long: "%A, %e. %B %Y, %H:%M"
    am: ""
    pm: ""
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem that could very well have been the same.

I fixed it by taking out the byte order mark from the localization files.

More info in the question I opened: [heroku not loading language file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868309/heroku-not-loading-language-file)

Answer (score 0):

Your locale data is for English (en) but your strings are, I think, Norwegian (no). What locale is your application running as? What language is your browser asking for? What happens if you add an `no:` section for the Norwegian?

As a wild guess I'd think that you application ends up trying to use the Norwegian locale but it can't find any configuration for Norwegian so it uses the hard-coded en_US stuff as a fallback. I'd also guess that everything works out on your machine because the default fall-back locale is no_NO; what happens on your local machine if you change the short date format in your `en:` locale section?

More guesses that answers here but this was a little too big and involved for a comment.

Comment: I get the error ActionView::Template::Error (translation m issing: da.time.formats.short)

Comment: What happens if you set up your `en.yml` with English stuff, added an `no.yml` with what you currently have in your `en.yml`, and then set `config.i18n.default_locale = :no`? Your problem is starting to look like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782007/heroku-and-i18n-problems