# App on Heroku won't update items, works fine in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm more than a bit confused on this one.

I have an app and it works fine locally. However, if I try to update an item in production on Heroku, it won't update and I get a "We're sorry, but something went wrong." message.

I've looked at several answers to similar questions and I haven't found a solution yet. Things I've tried:

- [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385172/heroku-language-locale-not-working) seemed promising but I'm only running english.
- Same with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868309/heroku-not-loading-language-file) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782007/heroku-and-i18n-problems)

I then started to start checking my gems. I ran bundle update and saw problems with nokigiri which led me down the path of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204152/nokogiri-error-when-running-bundle-install) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29020478/error-installing-nokogiri-on-bundle-install-but-already-installed) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27496498/failing-to-install-nokogiri-gem). But nothing has worked so far.

I've downloaded and updated the Command Line tools to the most recent version as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204152/nokogiri-error-when-running-bundle-install) too.

Here are my heroku logs:

```
2016-02-24T18:03:37.639284+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-02-24T18:03:37.639347+00:00 app[web.1]:     23:   <dd><%= @sailing_class.limit %></dd>
2016-02-24T18:03:37.639353+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-02-24T18:03:37.639279+00:00 app[web.1]:     26:   <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:unit) %>:</strong></dt>
2016-02-24T18:03:37.639351+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/sailing_classes/show.html.erb:25:in `_app_views_sailing_classes_show_html_erb___4311253642492843941_69812114208320'
2016-02-24T18:03:37.639347+00:00 app[web.1]:     24:   <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:price) %>:</strong></dt>
2016-02-24T18:03:37.639281+00:00 app[web.1]:     28:   <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:link) %>:</strong></dt>
2016-02-24T18:03:37.639353+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-02-24T18:03:37.639349+00:00 app[web.1]:     26:   <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:unit) %>:</strong></dt>
2016-02-24T18:03:37.616956+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
2016-02-24T18:03:37.639352+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/sailing_classes_controller.rb:18:in `show'
2016-02-24T18:03:37.639346+00:00 app[web.1]:     22:   <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:limit) %>:</strong></dt>
2016-02-24T18:03:37.639348+00:00 app[web.1]:     25:   <dd><%= number_to_currency(@sailing_class.price, :locale => 'en_us', :precision => 0) %></dd>
2016-02-24T18:03:37.639277+00:00 app[web.1]:     23:   <dd><%= @sailing_class.limit %></dd>
2016-02-24T18:03:37.505267+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/sailing_classes/1" host=www.clssmi.com request_id=a2b0cdcf-8591-4039-9b5f-d12d09caf37f fwd="50.172.246.24" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=138ms status=302 bytes=1153
2016-02-24T18:03:37.639350+00:00 app[web.1]:     27:   <dd><%= @sailing_class.unit %></dd>
2016-02-24T18:03:37.608121+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/sailing_classes/1" host=www.clssmi.com request_id=9fe48739-dc16-41ed-a8ba-668e047543d1 fwd="50.172.246.24" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=35ms status=500 bytes=919
2016-02-24T18:03:37.615055+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/sailing_classes/1" for 50.172.246.24 at 2016-02-24 18:03:37 +0000
2016-02-24T18:03:37.882720+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=www.clssmi.com request_id=2ea318c8-6a64-409d-aa99-9892af1065f8 fwd="50.172.246.24" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=14ms status=304 bytes=133
2016-02-24T18:03:43.427418+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SailingClassesController#index as HTML
2016-02-24T18:03:43.426514+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/sailing_classes" for 50.172.246.24 at 2016-02-24 18:03:43 +0000
2016-02-24T18:03:43.427414+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SailingClassesController#index as HTML
2016-02-24T18:03:43.453065+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 26ms (Views: 20.6ms | ActiveRecord: 4.4ms)
2016-02-24T18:03:43.451359+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered sailing_classes/index.html.erb within layouts/application (23.0ms)
2016-02-24T18:03:43.426518+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/sailing_classes" for 50.172.246.24 at 2016-02-24 18:03:43 +0000
2016-02-24T18:03:43.451365+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered sailing_classes/index.html.erb within layouts/application (23.0ms)
2016-02-24T18:03:43.453070+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 26ms (Views: 20.6ms | ActiveRecord: 4.4ms)
2016-02-24T18:03:43.423880+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/sailing_classes" host=www.clssmi.com request_id=8b816065-1802-4a00-ae19-457f0fd95234 fwd="50.172.246.24" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=35ms status=200 bytes=22475
2016-02-24T18:03:43.555976+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-18e331053335285eeca7290a575ccd04.js" host=www.clssmi.com request_id=efd055c7-1301-41ed-8e37-dbf832b9f720 fwd="50.172.246.24" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=133
2016-02-24T18:03:44.048723+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=www.clssmi.com request_id=2bc7d207-a01c-4a0f-8b97-6ede689acd4d fwd="50.172.246.24" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=228
2016-02-24T18:03:43.561012+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-4f42f332e5c3dd07dc6c8b9c3e70c386.css" host=www.clssmi.com request_id=9eb0e376-b2b7-4ffa-a4e5-b1cf0ad609fb fwd="50.172.246.24" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=133
2016-02-24T18:04:39.694568+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered sailing_classes/_form.html.erb (16.8ms)
2016-02-24T18:04:39.694819+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered sailing_classes/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (17.8ms)
2016-02-24T18:04:39.671315+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/sailing_classes/1/edit" for 50.172.246.24 at 2016-02-24 18:04:39 +0000
2016-02-24T18:04:39.671562+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/sailing_classes/1/edit" for 50.172.246.24 at 2016-02-24 18:04:39 +0000
2016-02-24T18:04:39.672944+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SailingClassesController#edit as HTML
2016-02-24T18:04:39.673052+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
2016-02-24T18:04:39.673006+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SailingClassesController#edit as HTML
2016-02-24T18:04:39.673082+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
2016-02-24T18:04:39.694613+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered sailing_classes/_form.html.erb (16.8ms)
2016-02-24T18:04:39.694854+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered sailing_classes/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (17.8ms)
2016-02-24T18:04:39.699681+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 26ms (Views: 20.9ms | ActiveRecord: 4.2ms)
2016-02-24T18:04:39.699750+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 26ms (Views: 20.9ms | ActiveRecord: 4.2ms)
2016-02-24T18:04:39.668594+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/sailing_classes/1/edit" host=www.clssmi.com request_id=ae08f28d-50c3-4916-bc5d-b7aabd06e2d0 fwd="50.172.246.24" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=37ms status=200 bytes=16848
2016-02-24T18:04:39.850919+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-4f42f332e5c3dd07dc6c8b9c3e70c386.css" host=www.clssmi.com request_id=bc003cf8-94a1-423e-9d07-912e01cd15e5 fwd="50.172.246.24" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=13ms status=304 bytes=133
2016-02-24T18:04:47.344532+00:00 app[web.1]: Started PATCH "/sailing_classes/1" for 50.172.246.24 at 2016-02-24 18:04:47 +0000
2016-02-24T18:04:47.344539+00:00 app[web.1]: Started PATCH "/sailing_classes/1" for 50.172.246.24 at 2016-02-24 18:04:47 +0000
2016-02-24T18:04:47.346227+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SailingClassesController#update as HTML
2016-02-24T18:04:47.386299+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 40ms (ActiveRecord: 25.8ms)
2016-02-24T18:04:47.480815+00:00 app[web.1]:     26:   <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:unit) %>:</strong></dt>
2016-02-24T18:04:47.386028+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://www.clssmi.com/sailing_classes/1
2016-02-24T18:04:47.386304+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 40ms (ActiveRecord: 25.8ms)
2016-02-24T18:04:47.480816+00:00 app[web.1]:     28:   <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:link) %>:</strong></dt>
2016-02-24T18:04:47.480816+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/sailing_classes/show.html.erb:25:in `_app_views_sailing_classes_show_html_erb___4311253642492843941_69812114208320'
2016-02-24T18:04:47.480815+00:00 app[web.1]:     27:   <dd><%= @sailing_class.unit %></dd>
2016-02-24T18:04:47.480817+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/sailing_classes_controller.rb:18:in `show'
2016-02-24T18:04:47.459326+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/sailing_classes/1" for 50.172.246.24 at 2016-02-24 18:04:47 +0000
2016-02-24T18:04:47.477060+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 17ms
2016-02-24T18:04:47.459330+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/sailing_classes/1" for 50.172.246.24 at 2016-02-24 18:04:47 +0000
2016-02-24T18:04:47.460391+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SailingClassesController#show as HTML
2016-02-24T18:04:47.385841+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://www.clssmi.com/sailing_classes/1
2016-02-24T18:04:47.460394+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
2016-02-24T18:04:47.480800+00:00 app[web.1]:     23:   <dd><%= @sailing_class.limit %></dd>
2016-02-24T18:04:47.480817+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-02-24T18:04:47.480817+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-02-24T18:04:47.476956+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered sailing_classes/show.html.erb within layouts/application (4.7ms)
2016-02-24T18:04:47.346365+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"kSzhpZMMK53yfJkRpU75csCW3m9MEQnvAxZcCeNpqGk=", "sailing_class"=>{"name"=>"KID LEARN TO SAIL&mdash;LEVEL ONE OPTI", "start_date(1i)"=>"2016", "start_date(2i)"=>"6", "start_date(3i)"=>"20", "end_date(1i)"=>"2016", "end_date(2i)"=>"8", "end_date(3i)"=>"5", "classtime"=>"10:00 - 12:30", "days_of_week"=>"Classes run weekly June 22 - August 7, Monday - Friday (rain or shine). ", "description"=>"Our Level One Opti class is designed for younger and more inexperienced sailors.  We teach the basics of sailing and sailboat maneuvering, as well as essential sailing terminology.  The only prerequisite for Level 1 is that the participant be able to swim at least 25 yards, tread water for a minute, and put a life jacket on in the water.\r\n\r\n", "restriction"=>"Recommended for kids ages 7 - 11", "limit"=>"22 students", "price"=>"150.00", "unit"=>"per week", "sort_order"=>"1", "link"=>""}, "commit"=>"Update Sailing class", "id"=>"1"}
2016-02-24T18:04:47.480803+00:00 app[web.1]:     27:   <dd><%= @sailing_class.unit %></dd>
2016-02-24T18:04:47.480802+00:00 app[web.1]:     25:   <dd><%= number_to_currency(@sailing_class.price, :locale => 'en_us', :precision => 0) %></dd>
2016-02-24T18:04:47.480788+00:00 app[web.1]:     22:   <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:limit) %>:</strong></dt>
2016-02-24T18:04:47.480805+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/sailing_classes/show.html.erb:25:in `_app_views_sailing_classes_show_html_erb___4311253642492843941_69812114208320'
2016-02-24T18:04:47.346249+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SailingClassesController#update as HTML
2016-02-24T18:04:47.480806+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/sailing_classes_controller.rb:18:in `show'
2016-02-24T18:04:47.460393+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
2016-02-24T18:04:47.346386+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"kSzhpZMMK53yfJkRpU75csCW3m9MEQnvAxZcCeNpqGk=", "sailing_class"=>{"name"=>"KID LEARN TO SAIL&mdash;LEVEL ONE OPTI", "start_date(1i)"=>"2016", "start_date(2i)"=>"6", "start_date(3i)"=>"20", "end_date(1i)"=>"2016", "end_date(2i)"=>"8", "end_date(3i)"=>"5", "classtime"=>"10:00 - 12:30", "days_of_week"=>"Classes run weekly June 22 - August 7, Monday - Friday (rain or shine). ", "description"=>"Our Level One Opti class is designed for younger and more inexperienced sailors.  We teach the basics of sailing and sailboat maneuvering, as well as essential sailing terminology.  The only prerequisite for Level 1 is that the participant be able to swim at least 25 yards, tread water for a minute, and put a life jacket on in the water.\r\n\r\n", "restriction"=>"Recommended for kids ages 7 - 11", "limit"=>"22 students", "price"=>"150.00", "unit"=>"per week", "sort_order"=>"1", "link"=>""}, "commit"=>"Update Sailing class", "id"=>"1"}
2016-02-24T18:04:47.460389+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SailingClassesController#show as HTML
2016-02-24T18:04:47.480812+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-02-24T18:04:47.480814+00:00 app[web.1]:     24:   <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:price) %>:</strong></dt>
2016-02-24T18:04:47.480784+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-02-24T18:04:47.476953+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered sailing_classes/show.html.erb within layouts/application (4.7ms)
2016-02-24T18:04:47.480803+00:00 app[web.1]:     26:   <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:unit) %>:</strong></dt>
2016-02-24T18:04:47.480806+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-02-24T18:04:47.480787+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error ("en_us" is not a valid locale):
2016-02-24T18:04:47.480807+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-02-24T18:04:47.477063+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 17ms
2016-02-24T18:04:47.480812+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error ("en_us" is not a valid locale):
2016-02-24T18:04:47.480804+00:00 app[web.1]:     28:   <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:link) %>:</strong></dt>
2016-02-24T18:04:47.480801+00:00 app[web.1]:     24:   <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:price) %>:</strong></dt>
2016-02-24T18:04:47.480813+00:00 app[web.1]:     23:   <dd><%= @sailing_class.limit %></dd>
2016-02-24T18:04:47.480813+00:00 app[web.1]:     22:   <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:limit) %>:</strong></dt>
2016-02-24T18:04:47.480814+00:00 app[web.1]:     25:   <dd><%= number_to_currency(@sailing_class.price, :locale => 'en_us', :precision => 0) %></dd>
2016-02-24T18:04:49.749766+00:00 app[web.1]: Started HEAD "/" for 50.112.95.211 at 2016-02-24 18:04:49 +0000
2016-02-24T18:04:49.751717+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as */*
2016-02-24T18:04:49.751734+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as */*
2016-02-24T18:04:49.753210+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.5ms)
2016-02-24T18:04:49.753265+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.5ms)
2016-02-24T18:04:49.755358+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 3.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2016-02-24T18:04:49.755409+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 3.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2016-02-24T18:04:49.749744+00:00 app[web.1]: Started HEAD "/" for 50.112.95.211 at 2016-02-24 18:04:49 +0000
2016-02-24T18:04:39.895627+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-18e331053335285eeca7290a575ccd04.js" host=www.clssmi.com request_id=979a64f3-a0bb-4983-acf8-76b3a2a36834 fwd="50.172.246.24" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=133
2016-02-24T18:04:40.461637+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=www.clssmi.com request_id=bbdf6ee8-5395-4f3c-91c1-1af30e4cdfea fwd="50.172.246.24" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=133
```

Here is the output from running "bundle install"

```
bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Installing rake 10.3.2
Installing CFPropertyList 2.3.1
Installing i18n 0.7.0
Installing minitest 4.7.5
Installing multi_json 1.11.0
Installing thread_safe 0.3.5
Installing tzinfo 0.3.43
Installing builder 3.1.4
Installing erubis 2.7.0
Installing rack 1.5.2
Installing mime-types 1.25.1
Installing polyglot 0.3.5
Installing activerecord-deprecated_finders 1.0.3
Installing arel 4.0.2
Installing multi_xml 0.5.5
Installing bcrypt 3.1.10 with native extensions
Installing callsite 0.0.11
Installing cancancan 1.8.4
Installing json 1.8.2 with native extensions
Installing excon 0.45.1
Installing formatador 0.2.5
Installing net-ssh 2.9.2
Installing mini_portile 0.6.2
Installing ipaddress 0.8.0
Installing inflecto 0.0.2
Installing uuidtools 2.1.5
Installing hitimes 1.2.2 with native extensions
Installing coffee-script-source 1.9.1
Installing execjs 2.4.0
Installing thor 0.19.1
Installing commonjs 0.2.7
Installing connection_pool 2.1.3
Installing hike 1.2.3
Installing kgio 2.9.3 with native extensions
Installing libv8 3.16.14.7 with native extensions
Installing newrelic_rpm 3.11.1.284
Installing pg 0.18.1 with native extensions
Using bundler 1.11.2
Installing tilt 1.4.1
Installing rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.4
Installing rails_stdout_logging 0.0.3
Installing raindrops 0.13.0 with native extensions
Using rdoc 4.2.0
Installing redis 3.2.1
Installing ref 1.0.5
Installing rmagick 2.13.4 with native extensions
Installing sass 3.2.19
Installing sequel 3.20.0
Installing unf_ext 0.0.6 with native extensions
Installing fission 0.5.0
Installing jmespath 1.0.2
Installing fog-json 1.0.0
Installing activesupport 4.0.2
Installing rack-test 0.6.3
Installing rack-contrib 1.2.0
Installing sinatra 1.0
Installing treetop 1.4.15
Installing bcrypt-ruby 3.1.5
Installing net-scp 1.2.1
Installing nokogiri 1.6.6.2 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/scottsipiora/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160224-55642-1nrqxpm.rb extconf.rb --with-xml2-dir=/usr --with-xslt-dir=/opt/local --with-iconv-dir=/opt/local
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
-----
The file "/usr/include/iconv.h" is missing in your build environment,
which means you haven't installed Xcode Command Line Tools properly.

To install Command Line Tools, try running `xcode-select --install` on
terminal and follow the instructions.  If it fails, open Xcode.app,
select from the menu "Xcode" - "Open Developer Tool" - "More Developer
Tools" to open the developer site, download the installer for your OS
version and run it.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/scottsipiora/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --enable-static
    --disable-static
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --enable-cross-build
    --disable-cross-build

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/scottsipiora/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/scottsipiora/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.2.0/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/gem_make.out
Installing timers 4.0.1
Installing coffee-script 2.3.0
Installing uglifier 2.7.1
Installing less 2.6.0
Installing sprockets 2.12.3
Installing rails_12factor 0.0.3
Installing unicorn 4.8.3 with native extensions
Installing rest-client 1.6.8
Installing redis-namespace 1.5.1
Installing therubyracer 0.12.1 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/scottsipiora/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160224-55642-1vhuyaf.rb extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lpthread... yes
checking for main() in -lobjc... yes
checking for v8.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/scottsipiora/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-pthreadlib
    --without-pthreadlib
    --with-objclib
    --without-objclib
    --enable-debug
    --disable-debug
    --with-v8-dir
    --without-v8-dir
    --with-v8-include
    --without-v8-include=${v8-dir}/include
    --with-v8-lib
    --without-v8-lib=${v8-dir}/lib
/Users/scottsipiora/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/libv8-3.16.14.7/ext/libv8/location.rb:50:in `configure': You have chosen to use the version of V8 found on your system (Libv8::Location::System::NotFoundError)
and *not* the one that is bundle with the libv8 rubygem. However,
it could not be located. please make sure you have a version of
v8 that is compatible with 3.16.14.7 installed. You may
need to special --with-v8-dir options if it is in a non-standard
location

thanks,
The Mgmt

    from /Users/scottsipiora/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/libv8-3.16.14.7/lib/libv8.rb:7:in `configure_makefile'
    from extconf.rb:32:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/scottsipiora/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/scottsipiora/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.2.0/therubyracer-0.12.1/gem_make.out
Installing unf 0.1.4
Installing aws-sdk-core 2.0.33
Installing activemodel 4.0.2
Installing actionpack 4.0.2
Installing mail 2.5.4
Installing fog-core 1.29.0
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.6.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.6.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Running Ruby 2.2.4 and Rails 4.0.2.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `ActionView::Template::Error ("en_us" is not a valid locale)` is the error.  `2016-02-24T18:04:47.480802+00:00 app[web.1]:     25:   <dd><%= number_to_currency(@sailing_class.price, :locale => 'en_us', :precision => 0) %></dd>`   are you sure that you have `config/locales/en_us.yml` ?

Comment: try maybe using `locale: 'en'`  instead of locale: ` 'en_us'`

Comment: Any chance you are vendoring gems and including the natively-compiled extensions? I've seen this error before and it came from using native extensions compiled on another machine.

Comment: Btw if you can't run `bundle install` how can you say "it works fine locally"?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it fixed.

[equivalent8](https://stackoverflow.com/users/473040/equivalent8), you were right, I needed to change the locale to 'en". But, then it exposed a problem with therubyracer gem.

To fix that I needed to do what I found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19630154/gem-install-therubyracer-v-0-10-2-on-osx-mavericks-not-installing/20145328#20145328).